# Sphinx Search MVA attributes

Tags: sphinx

We are looking into upgrading our Sphinx to version 3.3.1 (currently on 2.2.11).
Now, we are running into an issue with some MVA attributes which are used for facets.

Snippet of our sphinx config:

> sql_attr_multi = uint applicantids from field applicantids

The applicantids column in the db is a string containing a comma separated list, some records are an empty string (not null).
This is the error we receive when making a query with applicantids as a facet request:

> column 'applicantids' (alias 'applicantids') has incompatible types
> across shards

We were wondering if this could be caused by the empty records being handled differently in the new Sphinx version?

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like you've defined the 'applicantids' attribute differently in different indexes. (shards are a another name for a part of a index)

Should use sql_attr_multi in all parts of the index. Even if it indexing an empty string - it should index that as a empty list.

Comment: I did check the config for all the nodes and the attribute is correct in all instances. So that's not the problem. Also, the same config worked fine on Sphinx 2.2.11